# Nodemailer - redirecting to success page

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, nodemailer

Trying to get my page to redirect from a node.js and express.js page after sending an email. The message gets sent and I am getting the console.log() in my terminal (using morgan for logging) but it's not redirecting me to the success page and I'm not getting a console.log error in the browser. It just stalls and then i get a localhost didn't send any data error. Never used nodemailer before but I managed to get the message sent, I'm just having a problem redirecting to a new page.

Thanks!!

//Success html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <h1>Success</h1>

  </body>
</html>
```

// Form Box

```
  <form action="/contact" id="contact-form" method="post" role="form">
    <fieldset>
      <label for="name">Name &#42;</label>
      <input id="name" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Your name" required="required">
      <label for="email">Email &#42;</label>
      <input id="email" name="email" type="text" placeholder="Your email" required="required">
      <label for="message">Message &#42;</label>
      <textarea id="message" name="message" placeholder="Enter your message here" rows="3" required="required"></textarea>
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
```

// Success HTML route

```
 app.get('/success', function(req,res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/views' + '/success.html');
});
```

//nodemailer
// POST route from contact form

```
app.post('/contact', function (req, res) {
  let mailOpts, smtpTrans;
  smtpTrans = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
    port: 465,
    secure: true,
    auth: {
      user: process.env.GMAIL_USER,
      pass: process.env.GMAIL_PASS
    }
  });
  mailOpts = {
    from: req.body.name + ' &lt;' + req.body.email + '&gt;',
    to: process.env.GMAIL_USER,
    subject: 'New message from Portfolio site',
    text: `${req.body.name} (${req.body.email}) says: ${req.body.message}`
  };
  smtpTrans.sendMail(mailOpts, function (error, res) {
    if (error) {
      return console.log(error);
    }
    else {
      console.log('success');
      res.redirect('/success');
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

wondering if you still stuck on the issue but in case, below worked for me.

```
app.post('/contact', function (req, res) {
  let mailOpts, smtpTrans;
  smtpTrans = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
    port: 465,
    secure: true,
    auth: {
      user: process.env.GMAIL_USER,
      pass: process.env.GMAIL_PASS
    }
  });
  mailOpts = {
    from: req.body.name + ' &lt;' + req.body.email + '&gt;',
    to: process.env.GMAIL_USER,
    subject: 'New message from Portfolio site',
    text: `${req.body.name} (${req.body.email}) says: ${req.body.message}`
  };
  smtpTrans.sendMail(mailOpts, function (error, res) {
    if (error) {
      return console.log(error);
    }
    else {
      console.log('success');
      // NOT HERE res.redirect('/success');
    }
  });
  res.redirect('/success'); // I MOVED THE REDIRECTING CODE HERE AND WORKED
});
```